# How do I define multiple formulas in excel?

Tags: excel

I have no idea if this is the right place to ask this, but I am really struggling with excel. I am trying to define two formulas in excel, and then make a 2 variable data table to run these formulas through.

My formulas are:

`Q = SQRT( 2*U*A ) / SQRT(h)` , and if you use that best `quantity Q` then the acquisition and holding costs yield a corresponding `TOTAL COST = SQRT( 2*U*A ) * SQRT(h)`.

We are then given a range of values for U and h, with A constant.

How do I define these equations in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, type this in (without the A B C... and 1,2,3... at top):

```
     A    B    C        D                                E
1    A    U    h      Q                              Total
2   123   1    100    =SQRT(2*B2*$A$2)/SQRT(C2)    =SQRT(2*B2*$A$2)*SQRT(C2)
3         2    200    =SQRT(2*B3*$A$2)/SQRT(C3)    =SQRT(2*B3*$A$2)*SQRT(C3)
4         3    300    =SQRT(2*B4*$A$2)/SQRT(C4)    =SQRT(2*B4*$A$2)*SQRT(C4)
```

Also, have a look at https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~pecklund/ExcelReview/2001_Documents/2001XLGettingStarted.pdf